# Dynamic required fields according to user's selection in Django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I would like to make two fields (repertoire and performer) required only if the user selects and submits a type="performance". This is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    EV_TYPE = (
        ('performance', 'performance'),
        ('other', 'other'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=EV_TYPE, default="performance")
    repertoire = models.ManyToManyField(Work, blank=True)
    performer = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, limit_choices_to={'role__type__contains': 'Performer'})
```

My form:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'type',
            'submitted_by',
            'title',
            'repertoire',
        ]
```

My view:

```
def event_create_view(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form_event = EventForm(
        request.POST,
        repertoire_required=(not (active_user.id == 17)), # if the user is NMS then the repertoire field is not compulsory
        initial={'submitted_by' : active_user.profile.id}
        )
    form_venue = AddVenueForm()
    form_profile = ProfileForm()
    form_work = WorkFromEventForm()

    if form_event.is_valid():

        this_event = form_event.save()
        return redirect('event-edit', id=this_event.id)
```

This is what I tried. In the above 'form_event.is_valid', I did:

```
    if form_event.is_valid():


        this_event = form_event.save(commit=False)
        if this_event['type'] == 'performance' and this_event['performer'] and this_event['repertoire']:
            this_event.save()
            return redirect('event-edit', id=this_event.id)
```

This doesn't work though (I still get a 'this field is required' when I submit). How can I achieve what I want to do?

**Addendum**

This is also not working:

```
if 

this_event['type'] == 'performance' and not this_event['performer'] or not this_event['repertoire']:
                messages.error(request, form_event.errors)
            else:
                this_event.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that with a `clean` method on the form.

For example you might do;

```py
def clean(self):
    """
    Validate the form input
    """
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    type = cleaned_data.get('type')

    if type == 'performance':
        repertoire = cleaned_data.get('repertoire')
        performer = cleaned_data.get('performer')
        if not repertoire:
            self.add_error('repertoire', _("This field is required"))
        if not performer:
            self.add_error('performer', _("This field is required"))

    return cleaned_data
```

The docs for form validation are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Fantastic, it works, thanks. Do I must add blank=True, null=True in order for the above code to work? Ideally I wouldn't want to allow empty repertoire and performer in general (e.g. in the admin interface etc.).

Comment: Yeah if you've got fields which are only required based on the values of other fields you'll need to ensure they're set to `blank=True` so that django doesn't make them required. It's then your job to ensure your form validation makes them required in your scenarios. It's often wise to show/hide fields like this with javascript so that the required fields only show up when they're needed.

Comment: Yep, that's the first thing I did, I wrote a JavaScript which both hides and takes the 'required' flag off. That wasn't enough of course and I had also to define the clean() method as you suggested. Anyway, all working well now.